# Passing Generic Class' Property to ColumnAttribute in Code First Migration

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, poco, dbcontext

I have an abstract class inherited in 3 POCO objects:

```
public abstract class BaseObject
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Post : BaseObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PostCategory> PostCategory { get; set; }
}

public class Category : BaseObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PostCategory> PostCategory { get; set; }
}

public class PostCategory
{
    [Key]
    [Column("Id", Order = 0)]
    public int PostId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("Id", Order = 1)]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

However, whenever I do 'add-migration' in Package Manager Console, I get error:

> Schema specified is not valid. Errors:  (30,6) : error 0019: Each
>   property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'Id' was already
>   defined.

Basically complaining the `ColumnAttribute` having same property name (`Id` property in `PostCategory` object).

I need the property name to be the same for creating generic class that is used in generic Repo class. That's why I have the Id in an abstract class. But, this gives me error on CF migration part. Is there a way to get around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ColumnAttribute` attribute, sets the name generated in the SQL server. Obviously the column `Id` cannot be generated twice.

Simply remove the `ColumnAttribute`s, allowing the server to generate the `PostCategory` table  peacefully.